# Facebook Graph API tagged_places missing results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions, facebook-checkins

### Issue:

I am currently developing against the **tagged_places** endpoint. I have noticed that the API is only returning the first tagged place per day, even though a user may have checked into a location multiple times. Can anyone tell me whether this is by design? I am unable to find mention of this limit anywhere in the documentation.

I have all of the proper permissions in place, and I *am* seeing results, it just is not returning the number of check-ins that I expect to see. I am working to upgrade from an old app still using FQL and I don't believe this was a limitation for us in the past. If there is anyway around this, I'd be very interested to hear it, as we don't want to lose functionality for our clients by making this upgrade. Thanks!!

### Example:

My test account has checked in to 2 different locations (A,B) on 3 different days, like follows:

- **Day 1**: Check-in to Location A (x1)
- **Day 2**: Check-in to Location A (x1), Location B (x1)
- **Day 3**: Check-in to Location A (x3)

When I call the tagged_places endpoint through Graph Explorer, I would expect to see a total of 6 check-ins. Instead, these are the results that I see returned:

- **Day 1**: Check-in to Location A (x1) *Note: this result is expected*
- **Day 2**: Check-in to Location A (x1) *Note: I am expecting an additional check-in for Location B*
- **Day 3**: Check-in to Location A (x1) *Note: I am expecting 2 additional check-ins for Location A*

Answer (score 1):

From [Facebook Graph API User Tagged Places](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/tagged_places):

> Tagged places are aggregated to within the closest 12 hours, so this endpoint does not provide a complete list of all items that would result in a tagged place.

It is likely this is what is causing the limitation you're experiencing. The page does not give any way around this issue and it is quite possible that the functionality you're looking for just is not possible with the Graph API.